# Migrating from one database structure to another

Tags: php, sql, database, migration, transformation

I have a custom-made site which I want to migrate to a commercial solution which appears more robust. For the sake of an example, let's say the site is currently running a forum script made from A-Z by a student and the objective is to transfer it to, say, vBulletin. What approach would be generally advised for migrating from one db structure to another? What should I look out for when analyzing differences between tables (users for example) and how could I go about automating the transformation of data from one db to another?

Comment: What technologies are involved? What sort of db structures need to be changed as part of the migration? In this case, why does a change in the script imply a database change is required?

Comment: @btreat: This is on PHP/MySQL. The data to be migrated mostly concerns users, profile information, friend lists and messages. The rest of the data can be added as such as there's nothing in common. A change of database would be necessary as the current site was made from scratch. It's not bad but it still needs a lot of work and the owner prefers switching to a ready-made solution. The idea will be to use this as a foundation and to adapt any extra features.

Comment: I'm afraid that a SQL script is the only thing I can suggest for migrating the data from one schema to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your "student" structured the DB, as well as how you'd generate any metadata that vbulletin requires. A forum is not just users and posts. There's usually a ton of other data alongside that will simply not be present and/or in radically different formats that a simple "rename this field" or "change that table" type transformation cannot handle.

When moving between two database-drive apps, there's likely to be a significant amount of data massageing required, and if the source (or destination) is poorly structure, it may not be possible to do it script-wise and only a manual process will work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If it were somehow possible to do something script-wise, how would you go about it? I see a few solutions. One would be to use PHP to connect up to the databases and read-transform-write data (timeouts or speed could be an issue). Another would be to simply reorganize data through Excel. This might bring up a few encoding problems. Or I could spend some time writing a desktop utility to either generate SQL or transform data in real-time. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I'd do some porting by hand, figure out patterns and glitches, then start automating bits.